# Importing javax.swing in python

Tags: java, python, swing, jython, jython-2.5

```
from javax.swing import JFrame


class MainScreen:
    frame = JFrame('Hello, World!')
    frame.defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
    frame.size = (300, 300)
    frame.setVisible(True)
```

This is my python code, here i am trying to import jframe. but i am facing the follwong problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hemanths/Dropbox/personalProject/Monopoly/views/MainScreen.py", line 2, in <module>
    from javax.swing import JFrame
ImportError: No module named javax.swing
```

Can someone explain how to import java libraries in python. and please let me know what mistake i did here.

Comment: The mistake is trying to import libraries from a programming language to another. You simply can't do it like that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza its jython tagged

Comment: @FooBarUser well, didn't read that. Anyway, this is already covered in the jython manual: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/GUIApplications.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its Jython, I can import java libraries in python.

Comment: @HemanthGowda the code looks the same with the doc, are you sure you are running the script with jython?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  i got the manual. but what is wrong in my program?

Comment: Perhaps you by mistake execute `python MainScreen.py` instead of `jython MainScreen.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, they are different languages, but you can do it if you use Jython instead of python. Jython is a python implementation for java, you can find more about it here: https://www.jython.org/